# Merge ids and sum values of two collections of arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following arrays:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "total" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "total" => 1
  ]
]
```

and

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "total" => 5
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "total" => 5
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "total" => 2
  ]
]
```

I need to merge them together, keeping ids and summing the results, so I would get the resulting array as:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "total" => 7
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "total" => 6
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "total" => 2
  ]
]
```

These arrays come from a laravel database query using the toArray() method, so answers containing laravel default collection methods are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
arr3 = arr1->merge(arr2);
arr3->map(function(itemM)use(arr1, arr2){
  return itemM->total = arr1->sum(function(itemS)use(itemM){
    return itemS->id == itemM->id ? itemS->total : 0;
  }) + 
  arr2->sum(function(itemS)use(itemM){
    return itemS->id == itemM->id ? itemS->total : 0;
  });
})
```